# EntityId annotation on an aggregare member in Axon Framework

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon

From the documentation of Axon Framework, the following is stated about the `@EntityId`:

```
Field annotation that marks the field containing the identifier of an Entity. Commands for a child Entity are
routed to the Entity if the value of the Command's {@link #routingKey()} property matches the value of the annotated field.
```

I still do not understand what would be the impact if I do not have it on my Entities / Aggregate Members. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The `@EntityId` is what marks a field in an object as being the "entity identifier" of that exact object.

From here, it's good to have an idea what the short description of an Aggregate is:

> A collection of associated objects, which in regard to data changes act as a single unit.
>
> Reference to it a restricted to a single unit, the Aggregate Root.
>
> And, consistency rules apply to the group of objects.

The first sentence here specifies that an Aggregate is typically not a single object, but several objects.
These objects consist out of Entities and Value Objects typically, which both have the following description:

**Value Objects**

> Objects that are fundamentally defined by their attributes. This makes them immutable.

**Entities**

> Objects that are **not** fundamentally defined by their attributes, but by a thread of continuity and **identity**.

Now, what I've shared is essentially just Domain Driven Design specifics. As you know, Axon aims to provide a means to correctly model according to these guidelines. As such, we know an Aggregate is not typically a single thing with just an Aggregate Root, but it may consist out of several objects, some of which need to be identifiable as well.

This makes the `@EntityId` a usable component whenever you have an Aggregate which has several entities in it. Marking objects as entities through Axon would be achieved by using the `@AggregateMember` annotation, making those objects "command handling members" of the "group of associated objects" which we call *the Aggregate*.

As you might have noticed, the main Aggregate class, *the Aggregate Root*, requires the use of the `@AggregateIdentifier`. This annotation is essentially nothing more than a more specific version of the `@EntityId`. Due to this it is meta-annotated with `@EntityId`. This holds, as the Aggregate Root is **required** to be identifiable, making it an Entity as defined in the description.

So, when it comes to when to using the `@EntityId`: you already are using it if you have a simple single class Aggregate. Using it distinctly would happen as soon as you have the requirement of several entities (Axon's Aggregate Members) which need to be identifiable too.

This need would typically arise as soon as you want those Aggregate Members to *handle commands too*. More specifically, if you have a collection of a specific type of Aggregate Member which can handle commands, you are **required** to provide the `@EntityId` annotation on those objects. Otherwise, Axon cannot know which exact instance you want to handle said command.

The specifics of having a multi-entity aggregate are defined on [this](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/modeling/multi-entity-aggregates) Reference Guide page by the way.

Comment: Thanks @Steven for your answer. Just confirming my understanding here so if we have an AggregateMember like List<Persons> then in that case we should mandatorily have an EntityId otherwise Axon cannot know which exact instance you want to handle said command but if we have like a Person as an aggregateMember then having an entityId is not mandatory?